# Make hierarchical menu using Taxonomy menu

Tags: routes, taxonomy-terms

I've vocabulary 'category'. I've terms in below orders:

```
cat1
  cat1-subcat1
  cat1-subcat2
cat2
  cat2-subcat1
  cat2-subcat2
```

I've menu item called 'category' which includes all terms.
So my menu structure should be like below:

```
<nav role="navigation">
<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav"> 
  <li class="first active"><a href="/" title="" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li class="expanded dropdown active">  <a href="/" title="" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown">Articles <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="first leaf"><a href="/category/cat1" title="cat1">cat1</a></li>
      <li class="last collapsed"><a href="/category/cat2" title="cat2">cat2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

It has displayed only parent terms. It doesn't included child terms of every terms. But i want to included these child terms.

How to do this?